# Download a JSON behind a login page with nightmare

Tags: javascript, json, electron, nightmare

I am trying to download a heavy JSON which is behind a login page.
The document is about 5mb and takes approximatively 60 seconds to load on my connection. I tried this code but I keep having a empty object as a result. 
Any ideas what is the issue?
Thanks!

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({
  typeInterval: 300,
  show: true
});

nightmare
  .goto('https://pageThatRequireToLoginThenDiplayJsonAsText.com')
  .type('[name=email]', '')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=email]', 'myemail')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=password]', '')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=password]', 'mypassword')
  .click('[type=submit]')
  .wait(25000)
  .wait(25000)
  .evaluate(function (page, done) {

    document.documentElement
    done()
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    // fs.writeFileSync('testOutput.json', JSON.stringify(result));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('failed:', error);
  });
```

Nightmare version: 2.8.1

Comment: Since you never `return` the document, it's no mystery that `result` is null.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I use nightmare.
Even with return the result stay the same. :/

Comment: I am using version 2.8.1 of Nightmare. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. 
Basically, I just had to load a second time the url.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({
  typeInterval: 300,
  show: true
});

nightmare
  .goto('https://pageThatRequireToLoginThenDiplayJsonAsText.com')
  .type('[name=email]', '')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=email]', 'myemail')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=password]', '')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=password]', 'mypassword')
  .click('[type=submit]')
  .wait(25000)
  .goto('https://pageThatRequireToLoginThenDiplayJsonAsText.com')
  .wait(25000)
  .evaluate(function (page, done) {

    document.documentElement
    done()
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    // fs.writeFileSync('testOutput.json', JSON.stringify(result));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('failed:', error);
  });
```